# Is there a way that you can set an Android Vivid to delete messages of the number you select

Tags: sms, htc-sense

How can you set an Android Vivid to delete text messages after a certain number that you pick

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the Setting of SMS app, when you see the SMS interface, you hit the menu button, then you can see the option